# Motor which can generate 12 volts and 1 amp output

Tags: dc-motor

I need a small dc generator which can generate 12 volts and 1 amp of current. The shaft of the motor is driven by external source. Kindly suggest

Comment: Try a motor that draws 1A at rated load.

Comment: What is the source and how fast can it spin the shaft?

Comment: VTC - Questions seeking product recommendations are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

The heating in the motor windings will be the same whether the current is flowing because the machine is being used as a motor or generator, so you want to choose a motor with a rated full load current at least 1A.

At the 12W level, motors can be very inefficient, 50% would be quite impressive for a brushed PM motor, though BLDC would be a bit better. Some of this inefficiency is due to mechanical things like friction and air resistance, some due to electrical like series resistance, and some due to magnetic like eddy currents in the iron.

The series resistance will change the on-load voltage (up for a motor, down for a generator), the mechanical and magnetic losses will change the shaft torque (down for a motor, up for a generator).

Very roughly, if we assume a brushed PM motor and take a wild guess that half of the losses are series resistance, then that means we need a motor rated for 24v to be able to supply 12v as a generator, at the same forward current. Assume you need at least twice the torque to drive it that it's rated to produce as a motor. You may get away with a factor of less than 2, but obviously still >> 1, on torque and voltage with a BLDC motor.

Comment: I am using wind energy as the input source to run the dc generator. What should be the specifications to get the required voltage and current in order to charge the cell phone device